# Javascript - Cálculo de notas escolares com uso de objeto, é possível?

Tags: javascript

Minha intenção é fazer o famoso algoritmo de notas escolares para calcular a média do aluno, que geralmente é feito com arrays, porém quero saber se também é possível com uso de objetos, minha tentativa foi esta, porém estou recebendo undefined como resultado:

```js
var alunos = []
var media = 0;
var soma = 0;

for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    const aluno = {
        name: prompt('NOME: '),
        nota1: Number(prompt('NOTA 1:')),
        nota2: Number(prompt('NOTA 2:')),
        nota3: Number(prompt('NOTA 3:')),
        nota4: Number(prompt('NOTA 4:'))

    }
    alunos.push(aluno);
    soma += aluno.nota1.nota2.nota3.nota4
    media = soma / alunos.length;
    console.log(media);

    // zerando os dados para realizar o cálculo dos próximos alunos
    media = 0;
    soma = 0;
}
```

Caso a pergunta não tenha ficado clara, o objetivo do algoritmo é receber o nome do aluno, suas 4 notas e após isso calcular a média dele.

Comment: Dê uma olhada em desestruturação de objeto, vai ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar uma função `reduce` aliado a desestruturação do objeto:

```js
const alunos = []

const calcular = ({ nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4 }) => [nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4].reduce((total, nota) => total + nota) / 4;

for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
  const aluno = {
    nome: prompt('NOME: '),
    nota1: Number(prompt('NOTA 1:')),
    nota2: Number(prompt('NOTA 2:')),
    nota3: Number(prompt('NOTA 3:')),
    nota4: Number(prompt('NOTA 4:')),
  };

  alunos.push(aluno);
  console.log(`${aluno.nome} ${calcular(aluno)}`);
}
```

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

---

> [**Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao).
>
> A sintaxe de **atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)** é uma expressão JavaScript que possibilita extrair dados de arrays ou objetos em variáveis distintas.
>
> ```
> var a, b, rest;
> [a, b] = [1, 2];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
>
> [a, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
> console.log(rest); // [3, 4, 5]
>
> ({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
> ```

Comment: Muito confuso, porém interessantíssimo.

Comment: @DiegoOliveira na realidade seu código pode ser melhorado pra simplificar o entendimento. Eu só adaptei o seu código para aceitar a média. Acho que no seu caso seria melhor ter uma função para preencher os dados, uma para calcular a média e na realidade eu nem utilizaria as notas como atributos, eu usaria um atributo "notas" que seria um array

Comment: Dessa forma eu sei fazer, só estava interessado em saber se também era possível com objetos.